# Does off-site Push notification work on Chrome or Firefox for iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, firefox, push-notification

Looking for information on compatibility for [off-site push notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API) on browsers, the following picture emerges:

- Most desktop browsers support it, as long as they're somehow open or running in the background

  - Except Edge, which has Service Workers still under development apparently
  - Except Safari, of which, so far, there are only rumors that some day Service Worker implementation might be considered (or you can pay USD 100 for the [privilege](https://developer.apple.com/programs) of using their [completely non-standard implementation](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/) of push notification that has nothing to do with Service Workers)
- On Android, Chrome and Firefox support it
- On iOS, Safari definitively doesn't support it (same as for Desktop Safari, only worse since it's for ["OS X only. Notifications for websites do not appear on iOS."](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/Introduction/Introduction.html))

However, there are iOS versions of Chrome and Firefox, but they don't seem to be the same codebase as their Desktop/Android browsers.

Firefox for iOS, in particular, [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_for_iOS):

> Because of Apple's App Store restrictions, [...] uses the built in
>   iOS UIWebView on iOS, which is based on WebKit

However, being restricted to using WebKit as rendering engine doesn't necessarily mean it's unable to implement service workers, or Push notification.

In particular, in the [Push Notifications page of the Mozilla/Firefox wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Push_Notifications), there is this sentence:

> Mobile is targeting Fx45+ to for initial support. Android and iOS will
>   leverage Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) and Apple Push Notification
>   Services (APNS) respectively.

Which, of course, sounds more like a declaration of intent or possibility, than of actual implementation.

So, does Push Notification using Service Workers work on Chrome or Firefox for iOS?

Are there plans to make it work on those iOS browsers, even while it doesn't on Safari?

Comment: Read the actual browser docs...not wikipedia

Comment: @charlietfl, happy now? ;-)

Comment: Makse no difference to me...just pointing out that reading official vs unofficial docs  makes a lot more sense